# cat using relative paths on mac

Tags: linux, macos, relative-path, cat

I am trying to `cat` 4 files one directory down to a new file, also one directory down:

```
cat ./dira/file.txt ./dirb/file.txt ./dirc/file.txt ./dird/file.txt > ./dire/file.txt
```

I can get this to work from the Terminal, but not in the following:

```
for i in `ls -d prefix*`
do
  cd $i
  pwd
  cat ./dira/file.txt ./dirb/file.txt ./dirc/file.txt ./dird/file.txt > ./dire/file.txt
done
```

where `pwd` prints the correct directory. I get the error: `-bash:  : command not found`.

Comment: What do you mean "how"? This should work just fine.

Comment: See my edits. This works in the Terminal, but not in a simple loop.

Comment: Is there any `\r`/`\n` or `\040`/`\240` confusion in your shell script?

Comment: The shell script is a plain text Text Edit document, so I don't think so. I don't see any bad line endings in bbedit, either.

Comment: FWIW, `\040` is normal [Space] and `\240` is [Non-breaking space].  You could have `grep`'ed over the file to check for odd characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a *non-breaking* space at the start of one of the lines in your file (easily done by typing option-space by accident during editing).  The shell would consider that to be a word and try to run the non-breaking space as a command; this produces the "bash:  : command not found" error that you see.

Comment: You can use normal spaces and tabs to indent.  I suspect that you accidentally typed the non-breaking version (which is a different code that isn't recognized as whitespace by the shell).

Comment: I probably used regular spaces in Rich Text which got converted to the wrong space in plain text. Thanks...